# Ubuntu Desktop newbie

Tags: 14.04

I use Ubuntu on all my servers and feel totally at home with it.  However, I have only just started using Ubuntu on my laptop and have several minor issues.  I hope that someone here will be able to help me resolve them.

- I switched to Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop because the hard disk on my laptop died taking Windows with it.
- I still don't have a hard disk so I have installed Ubuntu on a 32Gb USB drive.  Whilst this works I find this is slow (I have a very capable Fujitsu Lifebook SH570 so the machine is not an issue).  Is this because of the USB or its size?
- Everything else too seems rather slow - e.g. saving files, starting/closing applications... . Will I see an improvement in performance if I install a replacement hard drive?
- I am using Ubuntu's file manager for direct SFTP access to some of my servers.  Whilst this works I have found that when I save a file I open for editing in this way an intermediate file with the extension .giosave#### is created.  This confuses INCRON on my server no end.  Is there some way I can avoid this?

I'd much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this because of the USB or its size?

USB. That machine has 3 2.0 USB ports. Those are slow.

> Everything else too seems rather slow - e.g. saving files, starting/closing applications... . Will I see an improvement in performance if I install a replacement hard drive?

Yes. Most definitely.

> Is there some way I can avoid this?

You probably want to install another sftp program. There are a lot of them but [filezilla](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/filezilla/) is pretty good.

Comment: Thanks.  The really annoying thing about Filezilla is that it insists on getting you to confirm every time you save an edited file.  I checked their forums - the developers insist that this is the right way to do things and will not contemplate making it optional. I sorely miss WinSCP and am even contemplating having some WINE.

Comment: Try "unison". Oh and the winscp is based of our command line scp. If tend to use the command line for scp more than any graphical program to do the same ;)

Comment: This could also be because you use most or close to all disk space. ext, the default filesystem, is meant to have some breathing room.

Comment: 32Gb is more than enough. / should not get over 10Gb on a normal system (a server would be different).